# Why is UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification not sent when the status bar changes height?

Tags: iphone

I've been trying to listen for changes in the status bar height – such as when the in-call status bar is shown or hidden, or the same with the internet tethering status bar – by listening for the UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification notification to be sent.

Fairly straightforward code here...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(statusBarWillChangeFrame:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

But the notification never seems to be sent in that case, either on the Simulator by using the "Toggle In-Call Status Bar" option or on the device when a call ends with the application open. In addition, the similar UIApplicationDelegate method is not called.

According to the documentation,

> **UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification**
>
> Posted when the application is about
>   to change the frame of the status bar.
>
> The userInfo dictionary contains an
>   NSValue object that encapsulates a
>   CGRect structure expressing the
>   location and size of the new status
>   bar frame. Use
>   UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey
>   to access this value.

Can anyone explain why this notification is not being sent in response to the in-call status bar being shown or hidden? According to the documentation, it should be.

Comment: Are you more interested in finding out why the notification isn't being sent for incoming calls or more interested in getting notification that there is an incoming call?

Comment: I'm not interested in incoming calls at all, read the question again. I only want to know when the status bar's frame changes. There are two major cases where this happens - when the in-call status bar either appears or disappears, or when the internet tethering status bar does the same.

Comment: I keep seeing in-call as incoming call. Sorry. What is in-call? I couldn't find that term, thus my confusion.

Comment: Also, this isn't quite the same as your question, but it does speak to in-call frame changes, I think. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114557/resize-for-in-call-status-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as if this is an active SDK bug. So much for that.

See http://openradar.appspot.com/6475681 and http://openradar.appspot.com/7080782.