# What Device to build on and aspect ratio for universal app

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, aspect-ratio

If I wanted to create a universal app that worked on all devices using SpriteKit +Swift,  what device should I choose to build on?

Currently I am using the iPad Pro 12.9 dimensions

```
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2732))
```

and then using

```
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
```

to apply it to other devices. This makes everything scale well but on the iPhone 11 Pro I have quite big black bars at top and bottom.

Should I choose another device to build on?

Thanks!

Comment: This question gets asked a lot and I remember asking this question too. Its also a good question!. That I've yet to see a really good answer for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hardcoding the size, set it to match the size of the screen.

```
let scene = GameScene(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
```

If you also want to account for the safe area insets (the notch of the iPhone X and newer devices with Face ID), you can do so as explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971598/4667835).

Comment: I had a look at the link you sent. If I set the screen size to the UIScreen.main.bounds.size, how to I draw my graphics? Do I use aspectFit?

Comment: @Questions it depends on what kind of assets you are working with. Vector graphics? Or fixed size images?

Comment: Vector graphics. So I was thinking I could design my app on one screen size with one set of images and then use aspectFit to make it fit all other screens? Is that a good approach?