# How to get height of tabBar on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift

I add `ViewController` above the `tabBar` like this

```
 cardViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardViewController") as? CardViewController
    addChildViewController(cardViewController)
    cardViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)

    cardViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - cardHandlAreaHight - tabBarHight,
                                           width: view.bounds.width, height: cardHight)

    cardViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true
```

the size of tabBar i get like this:

```
tabBarHight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

This is works for all iPhones but not for iPhone X
how to fix this moment ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried constraints?

Comment: Why do you want the height of it anyway?

Comment: @Vyacheslav no. This is Card View, aka bottom sheet this view will animating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case the right way to get this point is not get the safeArea but get point of tabBarFrame like this

```
let topTapbarPosition = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.minY
```

after that use it like this

```
cardViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topTapbarPosion! - cardHeight!,

                                           width: view.bounds.width, height: cardHeight!)
```

It will be work fine at all models of iPhones

Answer (score 1):

You should position the added view via Auto Layout, instead of setting the frame.

But if you really need to work with pixel sizes, you can access to bottom padding via

```
view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

You should also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831519/2133377

Comment: can you give an example how to add ViewController via Auto Layout? And how Can i use view.safeAreaInsets.bottom in my case? set Y at view.safeAreaInsets.bottom

Comment: For Auto Layout have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html For the solution with `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom`. you have to replace `tabBarHight` with `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom`

Comment: this will be works only in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but I need this value in moment of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Answer don't solve my problem, I need to know this value at the viewDidLoad. Have you any Ideas?

Comment: But viewDidLoad() is the wrong place to determine the size of views. Therefore you should use Auto Layout or place the calculation in viewDidLayoutSubviews().