# How to get Height of Safe Area Programmatically Prior to IOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uiview, safearealayoutguide

Without using safeAreaLayoutGuide (I am targeting IOS 9+), is there any way to programmatically get the height of the "safe area" in IOS without having to create a new view (constrained to the safe area) solely for this purpose?

I can't set an outlet to the safe area because it's not a UIView... or even a class of any sort.

And if I simply use self.view.height in the ViewController, it's going to be too high (wrong).

Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`? If so you can check its `length` properties and subtract it from the view's height. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683870/9086770

Comment: While there may be some overlap in answers, this is a different question... that one is asking specifically about ios 11 or higher, this one is asking specifically about lower than 11.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a `UIViewController` you can use the top and bottom layout guides like this:

```
let safeAreHeight = self.view.frame.height - self.topLayoutGuide.length - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
```

For `UIView` you can use the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` with a conditional check:

```
let verticalSafeAreaInset: CGFloat
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  verticalSafeAreaInset = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
} else {
  verticalSafeAreaInset = 0.0
}
let safeAreaHeight = self.view.frame.height - verticalSafeAreaInset
```

As devices running iOS 9 and 10 have no safe area, it is safe to default to 0.0.

Comment: That was highly educational!