# How do you get the safe area coordinates of a view programmatically in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Put simply, I want to get the bounds of this blue rectangle using Swift code:

[image]

The coordinates of this rectangle are visible in the Size inspector:

[image]

In an empty App project in Xcode, I've tried using `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame` to get the CGRect, but this property seems to contain the bounds of the entire view, not the safe area. Specifically, it returns `0.0`, `0.0`, `896.0` and `414.0` for `minX`, `minY`, `width` and `height` respectively.

I've also tried to get the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties of `view.safeAreaInsets`, but this returns 0 for each of them.

I've also tried to get the `view.superview` in case there was another view on top, but it returned `nil`.

All these values come from the iPhone 11. I'm using Xcode 12.

Comment: Have you come across this post. This could some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850392/390102

Comment: "I've also tried to get the top, bottom, left and right properties of `view.safeAreaInsets`, but this returns 0 for each of them." Well, I assure they are not zero. You probably tried to get them _at the wrong time_. But you know what? _You didn't show any code._ So it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get the safe area insets. (Wait until they are known before you get them.) Okay, what are they inset from? The view controller's view. So simply *apply* those insets to the view controller's view's bounds and you have the rect of your rectangle (in view coordinates).

So, I believe this is the rectangle you were looking for?

[image]

How I did that:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for v in self.view.subviews {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view.addSubview(v)
    // okay, ready? here we go ...
    let r = self.view.bounds.inset(by:self.view.safeAreaInsets) // *
    v.frame = r
}
```

Remember, that rect, `r`, is in view coordinates. If you need the rect in some other coordinate system, there are coordinate conversion methods you can call.

Comment: That solved it, thanks. The two mistakes I made were using `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and trying to use `view.safeAreaInsets` directly instead of using that `inset(by:)` function.

Comment: You can use the insets directly but you have to know how. In fact that’s what I did in the first version of my code. So it can be done!