# How to find View Controller height programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a simple question, how do I find the height of the View Controller programmatically when I have it set to freeform?

I want to do something like:

```
let viewControllerHeight = viewController.contentSize.height
```

[image: This is what I'm trying to find]

Also, how do I post an image on here without it being a link?

Comment: After you gain more reputation you unlock the image attach perk

Comment: self.view.frame.height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as `UIViewController` height because this class is only a CONTROLLER of a view. You can get the height of its view in a very simple way

```
let height = viewController.view.frame.size.height
```

Please note that this value may be incorrect in `viewDidLoad` and you need to check it later. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)

Answer (score 1):

The simulated size affects the size of the `UIViewController`’s `view` in the Storyboard.  If you access `self.view.frame.size.height` in `viewDidLoad()` you will see that value.  After the view appears, in `viewDidAppear()`, the `frame` of the view will be adjusted for the screen size and orientation of the device your app is running on.

Until you have enough rep, your pictures show as links. You can fix this by editing your question or answer and adding a `!` before the link usage like I did for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  let viewControllerHeight = viewController.view.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the safe area height is your viewController height. So you can find it like this

```
let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
let height = guide.layoutFrame.size.height
```

Please have a look on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831423/5701085)