# iOS and Swift - Getting the screen position of an object to set the location of another object

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app that places an image at a vertical position that is relative to wherever a particular input slider is placed, which can vary depending on the phone and the safe area at the top.  The code works fine except on iPhone X.

Here's how I get the vertical position of the slider and then calculate the y position of the image based on my "rate" variable.

```
var zeroVert = Int(slider8.center.y)
var vertical: Int = zeroVert - 6 - Int(rate*20)
```

How do I programmatically adjust this for the safe area?

[update]   I just now tried to get the safe area inset (using iPhone Xs max simulator), but it returns zero.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   insetTop = Int(view.safeAreaInsets.top)
}
```

[update 2]  Now that I think of it, I shouldn't care about the safe area margin as long as the position of the slider is known correctly.  The image is just offset from that.  So my problem is that I can't seem to fetch the proper position of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution.  It's based on bsod's answer here:
[Get safe area inset top and bottom heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829840/get-safe-area-inset-top-and-bottom-heights/49683870#49683870)

Fetching the position of a screen object is not relevant until the subviews have been layed out.

```html
    var zeroVert: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        zeroVert = Int(slider8.center.y)  // My slider
        placeArrows()  // The function that places the image based on the slider position
    }
```

This appears to be working.  My placeArrows() function is called elsewhere and I think that may now be redundant since it's being called repetitively anytime the subviews are laid out.  But it's a brief function and goes by quickly.  Good enough for now unless you can help me figure out a better way.

If I don't run the placeArrows() function AFTER I have the valid position of the slider, it uses the initialized value of zeroVert, which I've set to zero to prevent it from appearing on screen.