# Status bar frame changes without any notification

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, uistatusbar

I have registered to receive notifications about the status bar frame changes, but they are never received.

Here is how I register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

In some places in our app, we show/hide the status bar with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:maximize
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

But it can also change size when personal hotspot is enabled or when in a phone call.    Is there any way to get the actual status bar frame when it changes?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2406175/1693173) implies that notifications don't work due to an SDK bug, at least for orientation changes.  Is that the reason?  Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hmmm... works for me on orientation changes but not with the setStatusBarHidden. I do get it called when I simulate a phone call on the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question was posted a while back, but this problem is an annoying one!  The `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` notifications only fire with orientation change and in-call status bar height changes.

I solved this by writing my own setStatusBarHidden category function that I use instead of the normal `UIApplication` function.  Unfortunately (as @progrmr pointed out), because the status bar height could be 20 pixels or 40 pixels (and we have no idea of knowing what a hidden status bar's frame will become until after it is unhidden), we can only reliably fire off a single notification with the correct userInfo (`UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`).  Here's what I did:

```
@implementation UIApplication (statusBar)

- (void)setStatusBarHiddenWithNotification:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
{
    if (self.statusBarHidden == hidden) return;

    [self setStatusBarHidden:hidden withAnimation:animation];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                    userInfo:@{UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey: [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.statusBarFrame]}];
}

@end
```

It's slightly hacky, but I like it because I can use the same notification observer to listen for both in-call status bar frame changes and my manual setStatusBarHidden frame changes.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This assumes the status bar is 20 points high, usually it is, but sometimes it is 40 (when in a phone call, when hotspot is active, etc), but this is a nice idea.

Comment: Good point.  I didn't know that setStatusBarHidden actually hides the in-call status bar.  I thought it only hid the normal status bar.  Well... I suppose you can modify this function to only fire the UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification notification and pass along the actual status bar height in the userInfo.

Comment: @progrmr I fixed the category function to use the UIApplication's statusBarFrame.  Unfortunately this means we can no longer reliably fire the UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification notification with the correct userInfo attached.