# How do I get notified when a user opens my iPhone app while in a phone call?

Tags: iphone, uiview

I need to adjust several views in the event that a user visits my app while in a phone call. Is there a best practice for being notified of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check the statusBarFrame property of the shared UIApplication instance. Take a look at [Resize for in-call status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114557/resize-for-in-call-status-bar).