# how can i tell when the phone is in a call when i return to my app without checking the status bar frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

i am using UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification to tell when the status bar will change, and this does help me figure out when the call in progress goes away, and the behavior is as i would like.

however, there is one scene in my app in which i take the full screen, and that includes hiding the status bar … except that i would like to not hide the status bar when in a call.

my understanding is that the only way this status-bar will first show up is if i (a) get a phone call, then (b) return to my app.

so … when i return to my app upon receiving a phone call … there is no green status bar.  (fwiw, the green status bar does appear when i tap on my app to make the status bar and nav bar and tab bar re-appear, so it's not that it is entirely gone; just hidden because i told it to be hidden.  in the simulator, performing the "Hardware -> Toggle In-Call Status Bar" works as i would like, but i don't think this behavior will ever really occur this way in the real world.)

i found the answer to [How do I get notified when a user opens my iPhone app while in a phone call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618799/how-do-i-get-notified-when-a-user-opens-my-iphone-app-while-in-a-phone-call) … but that only works if the statusBar is visible when my app is re-opened.

i want to know how to tell that i'm in a call when i return to my app so that i can manually unhide the green status bar while the user is looking at my scene that otherwise will hide the status bar.

my question is thus:  is there an interface to tell me this information that i can query when i return to the app in applicationDidBecomeActive: or via some other sort of notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTCallCenter to find out if there is a current cell call. You and also register a handler with this class to be notified about cell state changes.

```
    CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

    // If no calls are in progress, the value of this property is nil.
    if ([callCenter currentCalls] != nil) {
        ... call present...
    }
    [callCenter release];
```

Comment: ok, this is basically the answer i was looking for.  of course, it has the disadvantage of being harder to test on the simulator … and of requiring the need to pull in the CoreTelephony.framework just for this one check.  but it really is much more to the point of checking if a call is in progress.  thanks.

Comment: a follow-up question:  will this work for VoIP apps that keep the status bar at 40 for themselves?  i.e. will they be registering with CTCallCenter ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's meant by status bar at 40 but I can tell you the CTCallCenter won't convey VoIP status. Also, the VoIP application will get it's own in-call status bar when it sets the audio session to record and play

Comment: 40 == 40 pixels, the current passed height of the in-call status bar on iPhone.  and you answered my question … as did some VoIP testing that i did which did not trigger the CTCall center.