# How can I get the original status bar height without in-call addition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, statusbar, uiapplication

If I read `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height`, then I get height of the frame of the status bar with in-call addition (press Command+Y in the Simulator to see it).

But how can I get the original status bar height without in-call addition?

Comment: How can I get original status bar height without in-call addition - is not clear , plz elobrate

Comment: For example, on iPhone 8 status bar height is 20. But if you receive call, then it becomes 40.

Comment: ya correct , but what concept you tried and what the OP you expect

Comment: I just want to get 20 - not 40.

Comment: see this it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114557/resize-for-in-call-status-bar

Comment: There is no answer there. If user launches the application with in-call status bar, then you can't track its original size!

Comment: are you tried `name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` it will throw the notification changes

Comment: I can track any changes if user launched the application with normal status bar and then changed it to in-call status bar. But if the application was launched with in-call status bar initially, then I don't receive any notifications about changing of status bar frame. And it's actually not changing in this case.

Comment: got it your point